# How to ensure I'm offline in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, connection

My new laptop will arrive in a few days, and much as I would prefer to avoid it, this time I'll be keeping Windows (going back to school and I'm sure some of the professors will expect everyone to use it). So now I have to think about all the security problems I never have to worry about with Linux.

The very first thing I want to do when it arrives is make sure it's not connected to the internet until I can install the antivirus software that I just downloaded. Obviously I won't plug in any cables, but it might pick up a wi-fi signal or something -- you know Windows, it's so helpful, always doing things without being told. How do I make sure it's totally disconnected? I suppose good old ping will work? If it is online, how do I disconnect?

Comment: i would not worry too much about the security of windows7, m$ invested a pretty decent sum into security. check out also http://blogs.computerworld.com/18791/think_windows_is_insecure_youre_wrong_says_security_firm_kapersky

Comment: Jeez, why do you think Windows just connects to.. "somewhere" when you don't explicitly deactivate the wireless device? Wow, talk about paranoid.

Comment: XP used to have nasty habit of connecting to any unsecured networks it found.  It's not an issue with 7 though.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like M$ finally managed to get their act together on security. High time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable the wireless adapter through *Network and Sharing Center → Change Adapter Settings*.

Comment: The best and most reliable way!

Answer (score 1):

Usually laptops have a switch for activating/deactivating Wifi. If no cable is plugged in and Wifi is disabled, I think you can be sure there's no cloud connection ;)

Comment: I think it's still called "Internet connection".

Comment: There's no standard place to find this switch?

Comment: @Tom Zych - Laptop Designs are not standard.  Just look for it, I think your over thinking this "security issue" to be honest, you don't instantly get infected with Windows 7, which unless you format your computer is what you will be using.

Comment: I mean a *hardware* switch. And as such, each vendor (even each model for same vendor :P) likes to put it in a different position... Standarization rules! :P And I said "cloud" connection on purpose, of course it's called Internet connection.

Comment: @Tom Zych: it depends on the laptop model you are using. macs have no physical switch. others have.

Comment: @akira: My Asus doesn't have a physical switch either -- only a keyboard button handled by the OS.

Comment: @grawity: "some have, some have not" :) do we want to list now all models? :)

Comment: It's an HP ProBook 4530s.

Comment: @Ramhound - Well, I don't know about Windows 7, but I do remember reading something a few years ago that said a new Windows box, being put online for the first time, would likely be infected before it could finish downloading all the service packs that would close its vulnerabilities. Hence my concern. Believe me, I will be using Windows as little as possible.

Comment: @Ramhound: yes,  years ago. not the case anymore with windows7. there were also times when you could sneak into unix mainframes by the use of `finger`. so, get over it. :)

Comment: @Tom - that's extremely unlikely if you are connected to a router with a firewall and you don't go surfing the web before you've installed the AV software.